# Log base 2 calculation in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the average disorder in ID trees. My code is below:

```
Republican_yes = yes.count('Republican')
Democrat_yes = yes.count('Democrat')
Republican_no = no.count('Republican')
Democrat_no = no.count('Democrat')
Indep_yes = yes.count('Independent')
Indep_no = no.count('Independent')

disorder_yes= Republican_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Republican_yes)/len(yes),2))+   Democrat_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Democrat_yes)/len(yes),2))+Indep_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Indep_yes)/len(yes),2))

disorder_no= Republican_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Republican_no)/len(no),2))+Democrat_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Democrat_no)/len(no),2))+Indep_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Indep_no)/len(no),2))

avgdisorder = -len(yes)/(len(yes)+len(no))*disorder_yes - len(no)/(len(yes)+len(no))*disorder_no
```

return avgdisorder

why do I keep getting math domain error?

Comment: Have you tried checking to make sure none of the variable values are zero? That is the most likely problem.

Comment: Thanks! How do I only choose non-zero values for the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the lengths are 0 or not, else you *will* get `MathError`.

```
if len(yes):
    disorder_yes= Republican_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Republican_yes)/len(yes),2))+   Democrat_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Democrat_yes)/len(yes),2))+Indep_yes/len(yes)*(math.log(float(Indep_yes)/len(yes),2))

if len(no):
    disorder_no= Republican_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Republican_no)/len(no),2))+Democrat_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Democrat_no)/len(no),2))+Indep_no/len(no)*(math.log(float(Indep_no)/len(no),2))

if len(yes) or len(no):
    avgdisorder = -len(yes)/(len(yes)+len(no))*disorder_yes - len(no)/(len(yes)+len(no))*disorder_no
```

If you want, you can always add the `else` clause for all 3 `if` statements as per your requirement.